# How to group date as day

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I'm trying to convert the date to something like DAY1, DAY2, DAY3, instead of normal Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.

```
rbind(DWReport__04,DWReport__05,DWReport__06,
          DWReport__07,DWReport__08,DWReport__09,
          DWReport__10,DWReport__11,DWReport__12,
          DWReport__13) %>%
           mutate( DAY = day(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")))
```

can anyone help with adjustment on the code ?

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to StackOverflow, please use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to understand how to ask your questions, so it'll be possible for us to understand and answer.

Comment: Your code does not give Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday. `day` just returns a number back.  It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you @Ronak.......what i want is to create a column that will group all transaction by date 
example of date dataset

Date
15/02/2021 23:59
15/02/2021 23:56
15/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
14/02/2021 23:54
13/02/2021 23:46
13/02/2021 23:46
13/02/2021 23:46
13/02/2021 23:46
13/02/2021 23:46
15/02/2021 23:40
15/02/2021 23:40

all transactions that fall under 13/02/2021 should be grouped as DAY1
14/02/2021 as DAY2  and so on ...

Thanks for the headup

Comment: See answer proposed on your similar question

Answer (score 0):

I think you've done the hard bit already.

Where you have `mutate( DAY = day(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")))`

I believe you could just use: `mutate(DAY = paste0("DAY", day(as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y"))))`